# Displaying a file in another file

Tags: files, sed

I was wondering how to print the contents of a file above the occurrence of a pattern in another file. I know that using
 `sed -n '/^PATTERN/i\\
INSERTING' filename`
would insert above the pattern but can i display the contents of a file instead?
This command got close
 `sed '/^Stephen/r siid' addrfile` 
but i want the file to be displayed before the occurrence of the pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '/PATTERN/r file' -e '$!N;P;D'
```

Doesn't work for PATTERN on the last line.

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/PATTERN/e cat file'
```